# How to use one image and have it scale responsive via media query?

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

I want to have a logo scale down to size via media query. I want to not have to not give the div that holds the image a specific height or width, and for it to scale down by percentage via media query depending on the size of the browser.

I have tried a few things with max and min width and height, but unless I specify the exact dimensions of my image, it disappears.

```
.landing_logo {
    max-width:100%; 
    max-height:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:30px;
}

<div class="landing_logo" style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/mj-logo-200_200.png')">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need media queries for this, you're using your logo as a background, therefore you need to add something like:

```
.landing_logo {
    max-width:100%; 
    max-height:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% /* try cover or contain to see which property fits your needs better */
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:30px;
}
```

Comment: of course, because your div is empty, so you need to give it some min-width and height. See http://jsfiddle.net/4wk6252o/ and how the code above (plus a random width and height I have added) works perfectly. Of course your min-width and min-height will be different, but you'll get the idea

Comment: I guess I don't see how "because your div is empty" when it had the background image in it. Is that considered empty? It's a part OF the div no inside the div is what you mean? I marked your answer as correct but want to know for learning purposes :) @Fabio

Comment: your div is empty means that in your HTML markup, between your `DIV` tags, you have nothing. The background is styling for an element, but keep in mind a div is a containing block that doesn't have any inherent size by itself, so if you give it a style (such as background), you need to have an element inside it or, most commonly in cases like yours, to provide a size. This way, the background will be shown in the div because now the div has a size. Otherwise, it's not that the background isn't there. It's still there, but your div width and height is 0, hence the BG isn't showing